# How to redirect an URL to react native app

Tags: react-native

How to open a react-native app from an url in safari (iOS) or from other app?

Example (it is android):
[image: Example]

I tried this way http://facebook.github.io/react-native/releases/0.38/docs/linking.html

But it is only for opening url from app in safari.

Comment: Using deep linking, try using the InAppBrowser component for handling authentication in the same app https://github.com/proyecto26/react-native-inappbrowser

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The feature you're trying to implement is called 'deep linking' and [this article](https://www.lullabot.com/articles/navigation-and-deep-linking-with-react-native) explains in detail how it should be done with react native for both ios and android platforms.

Answer (score 2):

For Android Virtual Device you should execute the following command from a terminal:

```
adb shell am start -a android.intent.action.VIEW -d "<app scheme>://<some>/<path>" com.<app name>
```

This article explains how to implement deep linking for React Native applications: [Deep Linking with React Native](http://ihor.burlachenko.com/deep-linking-with-react-native/)